# What is wrong with this MySQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

```
$my->query("UPDATE ideas 
               SET category = 'Document Options', 
                   category_id = '4',
                   status = 'Released',
                   status_id = '3', 
                   title = 'Support for iPad', 
                   idea = 'Add support for iPad. Allow uploads and downloads via the anonymous App for iPhone and iPad.', 
                   release = '0',
                   release_date = ''
             WHERE id = '225'");
```

`$my` is a custom class which contains a lot of other mysql commands. To prove it works fine it works great for the following query:

```
$my->query("UPDATE idea_feedback
               SET Feedback = '$feedback',
                   Date = '$fdate' 
             WHERE ID = '$i'");
```

Comment: what type of error are you getting?

Comment: Why the question? The query looks OK to me (except maybe `release_date = ''` should be `release_date = NULL` - Not sure if MySQL will implicitly cast that to some sort of default datetime?). are you getting any errors?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it in terms of syntax, but I think we really need more information. What's the MySQL error you get?

Comment: do not quote integers. Also, what's the error you get ?

Comment: @Ryan: We can't help you without knowing what error you get. You do know about `mysql_error()`, don't you?

Comment: Hey guys, no error was being thrown that I can find, and the empty '' didn't turn out to be a problem. Thanks a lot for all your help. It turns out that it was just the release keyword as Richard said below. Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Release is a keyword, backtick it

```
$my->query("UPDATE ideas SET category='Document Options', category_id='4',
            status='Released', status_id='3', title='Support for iPad',
            idea='Add support for iPad. Allow uploads and downloads via the anonymous App for iPhone and iPad.',
            `release`='0', release_date='' WHERE id='225'");
```

Notes:

1. release_date='' set it to the invalid date marker '0000-00-00'
2. please don't quote numbers, even if MySQL allows you to

Comment: +1 You are right. Although `status` and `date` (the latter used in the working query) are also keywords. But they probably don't create ambiguity for MySQL in a query, and therefor don't fail.

Comment: @fireeyedboy - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html `Release` is in the list, date/status are not

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it in fact. I reorganized this page to stop checking if values were different and just update them all since it's an admin page. It turns out that the release key was never used until I did this. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Ah yes, I should have checked that list first. I was going by the highlighting in MySQL query client. :) However about `date` (and I presume this also counts for `status`) the same manual page states: "MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them.". That explains it a bit more even.